# CollectionType element validation error message location

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm working with a `CollectionType` field.

```
$builder->add('urls', CollectionType::class, [
    'allow_add'=>true,
    'entry_type'=>UrlType::class,
    'constraints'=>new All([
        'constraints'=>[
            new Url()
        ]
    ])
]);
```

It works as I expected. Except the message if field has an invalid content.

Validator works but error message is a bit confusing: `Field.0 - This value is not a valid URL address`. What do I need is to simply make a parent field invalid - bind error to `urls` field.

Of course, I could create a form listener and perform validation there. But - IMO - it's a workaround.

How to achieve this in a "pure" way? I've tried playing `error_bubbling` in many ways but it's still not something satisfying.

Comment: Did you try `error_mapping` option?

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek - dozen of times. Do you mean any particular expression?

Answer (score 0):

try, so you for force validation on each UrlType and have it bubble the error upwards to the parent form, the CollectionType

```
$builder->add('urls', CollectionType::class, [
  'allow_add'=>true,
  'entry_type'=>UrlType::class,
  'constraints'=>new All([
      'constraints'=>[
          new Url()
      ]
  ]),
  'cascade_validation' => true,
  'entry_options'  => array('error_bubbling' => true)
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately - I still get ``Field.0 - ...`` message.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set error_mapping:

```
$builder->add('urls', CollectionType::class, [
    'allow_add'=>true,
    'entry_type'=>UrlType::class,
    'constraints'=>new All([
        'constraints'=>[
            new Url()
        ]
    ]),
    'cascade_validation' => true,
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'error_mapping' => [
        'your_parent_form_alias.field_name' => 'field_name',
    ]
]);
```

and then in UrlValidator when you are building violation add atPath like that:

```
        if (empty($form['field_name'])) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->getMessageName())
                ->atPath('your_parent_form_alias.field_name')
                ->addViolation();
        }
```

I'm not sure does error_mapping and error_bubbling shouldn't be mapped first for Url() and later one more time for All().

I hope it will help you

Comment: #1 - I'm using Symfony 2.8/3.0 so I'm afraid aliasing may not work as you wrote; #2 - does your concept need to alter vendor UrlValidator?

Comment: #1 This solution is for symfony 2.5, don't know does it work for latest version
#2 No, I called UrlValidator as I thought it custom validator not the one which is from symfony2
In documentation [error_mapping](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#error-mapping) there is error_mapping for symfony3 as well. I think that's the way how you should try to do it.

Comment: I've tried to experiment with ``error_mapping`` but with no satisfying results, it's why I'm asking.